# exporting channel - not the data

Tags: channel, export

I have a new channel (locally) about 30 fields long I want to get this into my live site. Is there a way to export and import the actual channel structure into a live site without doing a  full database dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that [Field Editor](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/field-editor) will handle this for you allowing you to import and export field groups along with a number of other useful editing features.

I'm not sure if you can currently purchase this addon however following a recent [statement from MBR](http://cartthrob.com/docs/docs_support/).

> As of Friday the 14th of March 2014, we removed from sale the
>   following products:
>
> Profile Edit
>   Field Editor
>   Affiliator
>   Champagne 2
>   Geofinder
>   Geotagger
>   CartThrob Subscriptions
>
> This means that CartThrob 2 is the only product we have available for
>   sale at this time...

It looks like it can still be purchased however so the current status is a little unknown. Best to give it a try and see but keep the official statement in mind with regards to the purchase and support.